# How to solve this second order linear differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

[image]

This is supposed to be easily integrated to give the given solution, however I found myself easily puzzled on where to start

Comment: Call $G=dF/dS$, so $d^2F/dS^2=dG/dS$. Your equation becomes a first order, separable one for $G$.

Comment: It's like solving $ax+bx^2 = 0$. You can "factor" out an $x$ term to get $x(a+bx) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually a first order linear differential equation:

$$
\begin{align}
0&=\left(v-\mu S\right)\cdot\frac{dF}{dS}+\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}S\cdot\frac{d^{2}F}{dS^{2}}\\
\\
&=\frac{2}{\sigma^{2}}\left(\frac{v}{S}-\mu\right)\cdot\frac{dF}{dS}+\frac{d}{dS}\frac{dF}{dS}\\
\\
&= \frac{2}{\sigma^{2}}\left(\frac{v}{S}-\mu\right)\cdot \exp\left({\int{\frac{2}{\sigma^{2}}\left(\frac{v}{S}-\mu\right)\phantom{x}dS}}\right)\cdot\frac{dF}{dS}+ \exp\left({\int{\frac{2}{\sigma^{2}}\left(\frac{v}{S}-\mu\right)\phantom{x}dS}}\right)\cdot\frac{d}{dS}\frac{dF}{dS}\\
\\
&=\frac{d}{dS}\left(\exp\left({\int{\frac{2}{\sigma^{2}}\left(\frac{v}{S}-\mu\right)\phantom{x}dS}}\right)\right)\cdot\frac{dF}{dS}+ \exp\left({\int{\frac{2}{\sigma^{2}}\left(\frac{v}{S}-\mu\right)\phantom{x}dS}}\right)\cdot\frac{d}{dS}\frac{dF}{dS}\\
\\
&=\frac{d}{dS}\left(\exp\left({\int{\frac{2}{\sigma^{2}}\left(\frac{v}{S}-\mu\right)\phantom{x}dS}}\right)\cdot\frac{dF}{dS}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{d}{dS}\left(C_{1}\cdot S^{\frac{2v}{\sigma^{2}}}\cdot e^{-\frac{2\mu S}{\sigma^{2}}}\cdot\frac{dF}{dS}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Equivalent to:

$$
C_{2}=C_{1}\cdot S^{\frac{2v}{\sigma^{2}}}\cdot e^{-\frac{2\mu S}{\sigma^{2}}}\cdot\frac{dF}{dS}\\
\\
\text{or}
\\
\\
A \cdot S^{-\frac{2v}{\sigma^{2}}}\cdot e^{\frac{2\mu S}{\sigma^{2}}}=\frac{dF}{dS}
$$

Comment: Clear and concise in exactly the form I want in the end! I guess I've been a bit rusty. Thanks!